# ElasticSearch Return only if Nested Date in range and occurs more than X times

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I am trying to write a query that returns only the documents if they have X number of visits in a specific data range. Ie Only return guid-docA if it has 2 visits that are between "2017-01-01" and "2017-12-31"

```
 **Example Data Documents**
 {
  "_id": "guid-docA"
  "visits": [
        {
          "name": "Sarah",
          "visitDate": "2013-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "visitDate": "2017-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jim",
          "visitDate": "2017-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "guid-docB"
  "visits": [
        {
          "name": "Brian",
          "visitDate": "2013-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kerri",
          "visitDate": "2016-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "Julia",
          "visitDate": "2017-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
  ] 
 }
```

I have tried script filter and can return the data if Visits count is greater than 2 but I haven't figured out how to get it if they have more than 1 (or X) visits in given year.

```
"filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "_source.visits.size() > 1"
    }
  }
```

Not sure how to apply logic to it for the specified count.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to be sure that `visits` field is `nested` [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/nested.html)

If so you can use a nested bool query with `must` clause and `minimum_shold_mathc`

Something like this

```
  "query": {
    "nested": {
     "path": "visits",
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
         {
          "range": {
            "visits.visitDate": {
              "gte": "2017-01-01",
              "lte": "2017-12-31"
             }
           }
         }
       ],
       "minimum_number_should_match": 2
     }
   }
  }
}
```